# Gnuplot: Range for arrows, how do I stop them from appearing beside the diagram range?

Tags: range, gnuplot

I need to plot spectra and in addition, I want to show some typical spectral lines. This is done with an automatically generated script for thousands of spectra, so I don't have the possibility to choose the lines to show for each spectrum, they should be chosen automatically by the xrange oder yrange. Sadly this ranges don't seem to work for arrows and so I need some other idea to prevent lines from being shown outside of the plot. I tried it with if-conditions, but this brings no change strangely.
Here is some extract from the script:

```
set terminal png size 1000,1414
set output "FeLoBAL_plot_1.png"
set multiplot layout 4,1 title "FeLoBAL-Spektren des SDSS DR12"
unset xrange
unset yrange
stats '170.txt' using 2 name "Fluss" nooutput
stats '170.txt' using 1 name "A" nooutput
set xlabel 'Wellenlaenge [{\305}]'
set ylabel 'Fluss [erg/cm²/s/{\305}]'
set yrange [-0.5:(Fluss_mean*3)]
set xrange [(A_min/(1.699+1)):(A_max/(1.699+1))]
p '170.txt' u (($1)/(1.699+1)):2 with lines title "Nr.: 170; J000256.55+092025.5; z=1.699"
if(2799 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 2799 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 2799, graph 0 to 2799, graph 1 nohead; set label "Mg II" at 2804, graph 0.8 }
if(1908 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 1908 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 1908, graph 0 to 1908, graph 1 nohead; set label "C III" at 1913, graph 0.8 }
if(1549 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 1549 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 1549, graph 0 to 1549, graph 1 nohead; set label "C IV" at 1554, graph 0.8 }
if(1240 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 1240 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 1240, graph 0 to 1240, graph 1 nohead; set label "N V" at 1245, graph 0.8 }
if(6562 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 6562 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 6562, graph 0 to 6562, graph 1 nohead; set label "H{/symbol a}" at 6567, graph 0.8 enhanced }
if(4861 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 4861 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 4861, graph 0 to 4861, graph 1 nohead; set label "H{/symbol b}" at 4866, graph 0.8 enhanced }
if(4959 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 4959 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 4959, graph 0 to 4959, graph 1 nohead; set label "O III" at 4964, graph 0.8 }
if(5007 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 5007 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 5007, graph 0 to 5007, graph 1 nohead; set label "O III" at 5012, graph 0.8 }
if(4340 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 4340 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 4340, graph 0 to 4340, graph 1 nohead; set label "H{/symbol g}" at 4345, graph 0.8 enhanced }
if(1216 > (A_min/(1.699+1)+20) && 1216 < (A_max/(1.699+1)-20)){set arrow from 1216, graph 0 to 1216, graph 1 nohead; set label "L{/symbol a}" at 1221, graph 0.88 enhanced }
```

Does anyone an idea of improving this or see the error, why this doesn't work properly?
Thank you!

Comment: Put the labels and their x positions in a data file and plot it `with labels` and `with vectors`

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with using if-statements in gnuplot. When i needed to do something remotely similar I used the ternary operator. It would be something like:

```
(Amin+20 < 1200 && Amax-20 > 1200) ? {set label 'blabla'} :\
(Amin+20 < 1500 && Amax-20 > 1500) ? {set label 'blibla'} :\
...
(Amin+20 < 1800 && Amax-20 > 1800) ? {set label 'blubla'} : 1/0
```

Also I would add these before the plot statement, but may be it doesn't matter. I think that with your statement many of them might be true at the same time, if for example A_min is very small and A_max is very large. With the ternary constract the first true statement is evaluated (more like an if-elseif-construct).

Another danger that can occur, depending on in what kind of environment you are using this script, is that the labels get `set` and never get `unset`. In that way, as soon as the statement becomes true it is true for the rest of the session and all coming plots get it. So you could try adding

```
unset label
unset arrow
```

in the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The two commands `set arrow` and `set label` do not respect the plotting area, because they are meant for decorating a figure everywhere.

Put the labels and their position in a data file and plot that.

Create a file `labels.txt` with

```
2799 "Mg II"
1908 "C III"
1549 "C IV"
1240 "N V"
6562 "H{/symbol a}"
4861 "H{/symbol b}"
4959 "O III"
5007 "O  III"
4340 "H{/symbol g}"
1216 "L{/symbol a}"
```

And then plot it with

```
reset
stats '170.txt' using 2 name "Fluss" nooutput
stats '170.txt' using 1 Name "A" nooutput

x(v) = v / (1.699+1)
ymin = -0.5
ymax = Fluss_mean*3
ylbl = ymin + 0.8 * (ymax - ymin) 

set yrange [ymin:ymax]
set xrange [x(A_min):x(A_max)]

 plot '170.txt' u (x($1)):2 with lines, \
     'labels.txt` u 1:(ylbl):2 with labels enhanced t '',\
     '' u 1:(ymin):(0):(ymax - ymin) with vectors nohead t ''
```

Since you cannot use `graph` coordinates for `plot`, you must calculate the equivalent values, which isn't a problem since you use `stats` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this!

Comment: Hi, it works nicely, but I have the problem, that the line positions are not convertet in the restframe. And I can't really interpret, what (x($1)):(ymin):(0):(ymax - ymin) and (x($1)):(ylbl):2 does and where I have to change something.

Comment: The four columns of the using statement are `x`, `y`, `dx`, `dy`, see the docs for the `vectors` plotting style. `x($1)` converts the values in the first column using the previously defined function `x(v)`. I assumed, that they match the values in your data file `170.txt`. `(ymin)` is the constant value of the variable `ymin`, `(0)` is the number zero.

Comment: Ah, the values of vector and label must not be converted, see my update.